# In which thread pool affinityRun submit a task? How to configure the number of thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, ignite

I'm inteding to submit large amount of small tasks into a node by affinity key.

```
Object affKey;
IgniteRunnable job;
//...
ignite.compute.affinityRun("cache", affKey, job);
```

The question is in which threadPool the given job is executed on each node? How to configure the amount of threads in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All compute tasks executes in [publicThreadPool](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/thread-pools#section-public-pool). You can configure it with IgniteConfiguration.setPublicThreadPoolSize.

Also, since ignite-2.0, you could define customThreadPool. Example you can find in [doc](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/thread-pools#section-custom-thread-pools).